# C#'s equivalent to Python's os.path.splitext()?

Tags: c#, python, split, utility

With Python, it has os.path.splitext() to replace the extension name to something as follows.

```
import os.path
names = os.path.splitext('hello.exe')
print names[0] + ".coverage"
```

And I have `hello.coverage`.

Does C# has equivalent functions as python's os.path?

### ANSWERED

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Hello 
{
    class Code 
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = "hello.exe";
            string newPath = Path.ChangeExtension(path, ".coverage");

            Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", path, newPath);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that both of these only remove the last extension. Renaming a file like "ball.tar.gz" would leave you with the file "ball.tar.coverage"; most likely not the desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension` does what you want:

```
string path = "hello.exe";
string newPath = System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(path, ".coverage");
```

**EDIT:** 
Your using statement should be `using System.IO`, and then you can use it as you have it or like this:

```
Path.ChangeExtension(path, newExtension);
```

Also, `Console.WriteLine` can't be used as you have it. You could do this though:

`Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", path, newPath);`

Comment: I run the code to get some error message. Could you check that?